# While creating a Maven project using archetype13, I have faced Sling IDE issues for core and test pom.xml

Tags: maven, installation, content-management-system, aem

while creating a maven project using archetype13, I have faced Sling IDE issues as below for core and test pom.xml

This is the error that I get:

"Missing m2e incremental build support for generating the bundle manifest, component descriptions and metatype resources.
Please use the provided Quick Fixes on this issue to resolve this.  pom.xml /AEMEditable.core   line 1  Bundle Project Not Supporting M2E"

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** Figured out how to solve this.

We need to manually modify the pom.xml for core and test, under maven-bundle plugin.

For both core and test pom.xml add the following code :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Configure extra execution of 'manifest' in process-classes phase 
                        to make sure SCR metadata is generated before unit test runs -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>scr-metadata</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <supportIncrementalBuild>true</supportIncrementalBuild>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <!-- Import any version of javax.inject, to allow running on multiple versions of AEM -->
                        <Import-Package>javax.inject;version=0.0.0,*</Import-Package>
                        <Sling-Model-Packages>
                            AEMEditable.core
                        </Sling-Model-Packages>
                        <!-- Enable processing of OSGI DS component annotations -->
                        <_dsannotations>*</_dsannotations>
                        <!-- Enable processing of OSGI metatype annotations -->
                        <_metatypeannotations>*</_metatypeannotations>
                    </instructions>
                    <exportScr>true</exportScr>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Check image:

[image: pom.xml file screenshot]

Once this is done, select the whole project in eclipse, right click, Click on Maven --> Update Project

Comment: Did solve the same problem I had. Thank you so much!